# Regex for Linux mount path to validate user enter path value in java script

Tags: javascript, regex, linux, path, mount

**I have a input field for Linux mount path in my form** 
I need regex to validate following cases :

**Should not allow user to enter**

```
/, /bin, /dev, /etc, /mnt, /opt, /run,/srv, /sys, /tmp, /usr, /var, /lib,  /proc, /sbin, /root, /boot, /home,  /lib64, /media, /opt/folde r, /opt/folder/, /usr/bin, /usr/lib, /usr/lib64, /usr/sbin
```

**Should allow user to enter**

```
/opt/folder, /var/folder, /tmp/folder
/bin/foldername, /boot/foldername, /devfoldername, /etc/foldername, /home/foldername, /lib/foldername, /lib64/foldername, /media/foldername, /mnt/foldername, /opt/foldername, /proc/foldername, /root/foldername, /run/foldername, /sbin/foldername, /srv/foldername, /sys/foldername, /tmp/foldername, /usr/foldername, /var/foldername
```

i'm tring with this one: `^(.+)\/([^/\s]+)$`

**but it is working for negative case like below:**

```
/, /bin, /dev, /etc, /mnt, /opt, /run,/srv, /sys, /tmp, /usr, /var, /lib,  /proc, /sbin, /root, /boot, /home,  /lib64, /media, /opt/folde r, /opt/folder/
```

**positive case like below:**

```
/bin/foldername, /boot/foldername, /devfoldername, /etc/foldername, /home/foldername, /lib/foldername, /lib64/foldername, /media/foldername, /mnt/foldername, /opt/foldername, /proc/foldername, /root/foldername, /run/foldername, /sbin/foldername, /srv/foldername, /sys/foldername, /tmp/foldername, /usr/foldername, /var/foldername
```

please can anyone here help me out thanks

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ZtJ4RK/3.. look here. is it ok for you?

Comment: @GolamMazidsajib [it doesn't](https://regex101.com/r/ZtJ4RK/4). You have the comparison wrong - the first line didn't match *only* because it ended with a `/`. Remove it and it matches. Moreover, it shouldn't be checking a comma separated list, but *each* entry. The regex is supposed to regeck `/bin` if entered by its own or `/dev` if entered by its own (and so on), however allow `/opt/folder` if entered on its own.

Comment: it is not working for the negative cases string that you mention right? https://regex101.com/r/fBiWGY/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/fBiWGY/2)

Comment: @VLAZ I see, but the line has an ending slash right?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I don't think the line is supposed to represent the only canonical input. At the very least, what if somebody just swaps some of the paths? Also, I don't think a string containing comma separated paths is the intended input, either.

Comment: @VLAZ Good point :-)

Comment: @Ram clear your question first....show which prefix u want to allow. and which prefix u dont want to allow

Comment: @GolamMazidsajib it should not allow following strings: /, /bin, /boot, /dev, /etc, /home, /lib, /lib64, /media, /mnt, /opt, /proc, /root, /run, /sbin, /srv, /sys, /tmp, /usr, /var, /usr/bin, /usr/lib, /usr/lib64, /usr/sbin, /*/foldername(with space and ending with slash)

Comment: @GolamMazidsajib sorry for the confusion
 but it should allow: /bin/foldername, /boot/foldername, /devfoldername, /etc/foldername, /home/foldername, /lib/foldername, /lib64/foldername, /media/foldername, /mnt/foldername, /opt/foldername, /proc/foldername, /root/foldername, /run/foldername, /sbin/foldername, /srv/foldername, /sys/foldername, /tmp/foldername, /usr/foldername, /var/foldername

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this regex:  `^(\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+){2,}$(?<!^(\/usr\/bin)|(\/usr\/lib)|(\/usr\/lib64)|(\/usr\/sbin)$)`

Look [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZtJ4RK/21) here

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212786/discussion-on-answer-by-golam-mazid-sajib-regex-for-linux-mount-path-to-validate).

Comment: can any one check in to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63580184/how-can-i-do-unit-test-for-setinterval-in-ngoninit