# Regex for linux mount path to validate path in js

Tags: javascript, regex, linux

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61494926/regex-for-linux-mount-path-to-validate-user-enter-path-value-in-java-script).

User wanted to give parent folder as to be from:

```
/foldername
```

It should allow dummy parent name(which is not there in Linux system) like

```
/dummyfolder
```

It has to allow single path like:

```
/foldername here folder name it may be anything like /xyz or /abc or .....
```

but it should not allow single path like this:

```
/, /bin, /dev, /etc, /mnt, /opt, /run,/srv, /sys, /tmp, /usr, /var, /lib,  /proc, /sbin, /root, /boot, /home,  /lib64, /media
```

Comment: now your question clear....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try with this regex: `^(\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+$(?<!^\/bin|\/dev|\/etc|\/mnt|\/opt|\/run|\/srv|\/sys|\/tmp|\/usr|\/var|\/lib|\/proc|\/sbin|\/root|\/boot|\/home|\/lib64|\/media|\/usr\/bin|\/usr\/lib|\/usr\/lib64|\/usr\/sbin|(\/usr\/bin)|(\/usr\/lib)|(\/usr\/lib64)|(\/usr\/sbin)$)`

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZtJ4RK/29) here

Comment: @Ram is this regex ok for you?

Comment: no bro sorry for the confusion here this the old regex ^(\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+){2,}$(?<!^(\/usr\/bin)|(\/usr\/lib)|(\/usr\/lib64)|(\/usr\/sbin)$) this is fine for me but here this one is not allowing "/dummyfolder" is not allowing so i need updated regex with this only one updated change it has to accept parent folder as any folder

Comment: it is not allowing /dummyfolder as parent it has to allow /dummyfolder or /dummy_folder/folder as well as old prefix nothing but this ^(\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+){2,}$(?<!^(\/usr\/bin)|(\/usr\/lib)|(\/usr\/lib64)|(\/usr\/sbin)$)

Comment: user can give parent folder as anything bro not only dummy folder /* or /*/* it has to allow

Comment: new ans is allowing old single path's wch is not allowed
 /bin, /dev, /etc, /mnt, /opt, /run,/srv, /sys, /tmp, /usr, /var, /lib,  /proc, /sbin, /root, /boot, /home,  /lib64, /media,

Comment: This doesn't work with javascript: https://regex101.com/r/ZtJ4RK/31 variable length lookbehind is not allowed.